# How to wait for one of multiple elements to be displayed first using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium so I'm looking for some insight on how to achieve this.

Essentially, I want my driver to wait for one of multiple elements to be visible. This is because the website can produce mixed results when using automation, so I want to treat this like it's "error handling" (if that makes sense).

Basically, if element a is visible first, do this. However, if element b is visible first, do that.

How would I be able to achieve this using the Selenium webdriver for C#? I read that combining the elements' XPath value by using "|" worked, however when I tried it with my application, I had no luck.

Any answers are greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Selenium can't do that since it's one call and then another... even if you use javascript to set two "setInterval" loops, these would not necessarily run at the same time so you would never know for sure if "a" appeared before "b".   You can know that either or both appeared, but not the order.  Quantum HTML.

Comment: I see, that's interesting. I essentially want to execute some block of code if element a appeared and continue with the program. Whereas, if element b appeared, I'd execute a different block of code and continue with the program. I don't think I'd need to know the order of their appearance. Just to know which one appears first so I can execute the block of code specific for that element.

Comment: ah, I think I misunderstood there.   It sounds like you're looking for WebDriverEventListeners: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this is kind of tough because your elements could be displayed within a split second of each other. Wonder if you could put this in a case and break when you get one?

So what I was thinking was seeing if the element was present first.

```
        public static bool IsElementPresent_byXpath(string xpath)
    {
        bool result;
        try { result = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Displayed; }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { return false; }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { return false; }
        return result;
    }
```

So if you do it this way, then you can write something like the below but my concern is that if the page is not changing, ele1, ele2 and ele3 could be invoked. So this code would need to be changed.

```
        bool ele1 = Browser.IsElementPresent_byXpath("//[@id='1']");

        bool ele2 = Browser.IsElementPresent_byXpath("//[@id='2']");

        bool ele3 = Browser.IsElementPresent_byXpath("//[@id='3']");

        if (ele1)
        {
            //do this
        }
        else if (ele2 || ele1 == false)
        {
            //do this
        }

        else if (ele3 || ele1 == false ||  ele2 == false)
         {
            //do this
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! The way the website works is say for example you get element 1 visible, I would have to restart the script because element 1 would be an error that I'm trying to catch. However, if we get element 3, then we'll continue since that'll be a "successful" element that I'm trying to catch. I hope this makes sense lmao

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. This may work? At least this way it should only invoke one.

Comment: I'll give your solution a try! Thank you for answering!

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner, this solution actually did help! Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Wait.Until](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_DefaultWait_1_Until__1.htm), so that I can combine the benefits of waiting with set timeout for an event, and returning me matching locator, so I can base my logic on the result.

This is java code, but C# has equivalents.

Assuming I am waiting for either `firstBy`, `secondBy` or `thirdBy`:

```
By locatorOfElementThatIsPresent = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds).<By>until(driver -> {
    // findElements does not throw when element not found, so I skip try-catch
    if (driver.findElements(firstBy).size() > 0) return firstBy;
    if (driver.findElements(secondBy).size() > 0) return secondBy;
    if (driver.findElemetns(thirdBy).size() > 0) return thirdBy;
    return null; // neither found, so the method will be retried until timeout
});
```